# Public Company Competitors?

Tags: equities, data, market-data, historical-data, fundamentals

Where can I input a stock ticker and get back a list of the top 3-5 competitors of the stock? E.g. if I input F, I get GM, etc. It would be great if this could also give me data for delisted stocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure: Thompson Reuters Eikon and Bloomberg.

I guess you are asking for a free version of this and it this point I have to say to the best of my knowledge that there is no such service.

Comment: Do you know what command could return the stock tickers of a small number of competitors (e.g. maybe 5)?

Comment: On Bloomberg: [Ticker] PBAR

Comment: On Reuters: just take a look on the overview page